# Is it possible to repair reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I have a rep of 130 with only 6 down votes in two years and yet have been locked out.

Is it possible to repair a poor reputation or is it a lost cause?

After reading the details on this subject it seems as though it isn't very likely, but maybe others here have already experienced this problem and rectified it?

Comment: Did you read the link in the lock out message? It explains what can be done.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers

Comment: Actually yes I did read it, several times, and have done the steps mentioned several weeks ago with no change. The only thing left to do according to the article is to contact them directly to which they state will have very little importance. So basically, if we have followed those steps and nothing has changed, is it pretty much lost?

Comment: It seems you missed the step *"writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again"*? Also, the lack of any detail and a description of what you've tried in this very question, makes me feel you might need to click the links about writing good questions. (But I did not look at your SO questions.)

Comment: You have ten self-deleted questions within the last year. As the above-linked answer explains, this really hurts you in the question-ban heuristic. Would you like for me to undelete some of these for you to edit into shape? It looks like that might be enough to allow you to ask questions again.

Comment: Ah I didnt realize that, I will look into those. Thanks Brad that will probably help a lot.

Comment: @Stefan - You probably won't see the questions until we undelete them, so just use an "other" flag on one of your other posts on Stack Overflow and ask to have them be undeleted when you're ready to edit them. I don't want to undelete them until you want to work on them, because they might attract further downvotes in their current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're banned right now. You're free to keep asking questions, though you're likely still on the verge of triggering the automatic block again.

We use voting as a measure of how much the community trusts your input, so the only thing I'd advise is that you keep the tips from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) in mind in order to attract upvotes to your questions.